# Running Total VBA

Tags: vba

I have the code below that calculates the example below

|1     2     2|

|2     5     7|

and so forth, the issue is when i run the vba more then once without closing access it gives me the example below

|1     2      9|

|2     5    14|

i just continues to add.  How can I fix this to start over everytime without closing access and re opening it?

Code:

```
Global GBL_Sum As Double



Public Function global_add(ivalue) As Double



    GBL_Sum = GBL_Sum + ivalue
    global_add = GBL_Sum



End Function
```

Comment: Don't use the `Global` access modifier, it's deprecated. Use `Public` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow...  is the third value just the sum of the first two?  I assume not and was just hoping for more context behind the question.

Comment: it's a running sum, 9+5=14

Comment: Mat thank you for the info however that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preamble: Assume you gave Peter 5 apples, one of them Peter ate himself and another shared with his sister Annie. How many apples has Peter left?

If your answer is 3, than you're wrong, because you have no idea how many apples Peter had before you gave him another 5.

And here amble comes:

```
GBL_Sum = 0
```

wherever you use it and whenever you want it to start summing over.

Comment: Public Function Init_Globals()
GBL_Sum = 0
End Function

Public Function global_add(ivalue) As Double


    GBL_Sum = GBL_Sum + ivalue
    global_add = GBL_Sum

   

End Function

Comment: I used the above for the GBL_Sum and it still keeps adding.

Comment: You added it to separate function, but you have to call it from very start point. If the calculations start with some button clicked, you should nullify that variable in the appropriate OnClick (or Clicked) event.

Comment: unfortunately they don't.  It's vba in a query criteria and is triggered by a macro for multiple make tables and a batch that runs at 4 am.